# How to play the right sound when selected on a object in unity/c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried by making a script to when I tap on a object on my scene to make sound. So, I have audio source and my script implemented on the object. However, with my script below it only deploys the first audio that i have which is (cup). What I want to change in my code or make it better is dont let audio run until I click on the object. and any way to do where I click on a object the audio triggers? please advise. thanks for the help.

**Update: Right now, if I select everywhere the sound triggers and whenever I click on other object it gives the one audio of all of my object, that is not what I wanted.**

here is my code:

```
    public class TextToSpeech : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] AudioClip _audioClip;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] float _volume = 1;
    AudioSource _audioSource;


    public AudioClip SoundToPlay;
    public float Volume;
    public bool alreadyPlayed = false;
    public bool playOnAwake = false;


    private Touch touch;
    private Vector2 beginTouchPosition, endTouchPosition;




    private bool isPlaying;


    void Start()
    {
        _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        _audioSource.clip = _audioClip;
        _audioSource.volume = _volume;


    }


    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            _audioSource.enabled = true;
            if (!_audioSource.isPlaying) {
                _audioSource.clip = SoundToPlay;
                _audioSource.Play ();
            }
            else
            {
                _audioSource.enabled = false;

            }


        }


    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Your OnTriggerEnter method does not match the signature of Unity [it is missing the Collider parameter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html)  
2. Make sure that the object has a collider with "IsTrigger" enabled and that at least one of the two objects has a rigidbody attached.

Comment: Is any script attached to cup or bottle prefab, or what's their name after instantiation?

Comment: you'll want to set `playOnAwake = false;` in your start functions too

Comment: So, I passed it `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`, and inside my `Update()` I have this  OnTriggerEnter(); but it wants arguments, and am I suppose to put `Collider other`? and I have rigid body on my object and I dont is `isTrigger` option on unity to check on that?

Comment: Man, wait, you don't even need ontriggerenter method as I guess, what have common ontriggerEnter and touch, You want that sound when you touch object or when other gameobject touches it?

Comment: @Jake so, if I place `playOnAwake = false;` and leave my code as is, will that fix the object selection part?

Comment: I want that sound when you touch object

Comment: So you don't need OnTriggerEnter method

Comment: if I can do it without the method that will be great

Comment: So, what is name of your cup after instantiation? or does it have any script attached to it?

Comment: Tell me and I give u working code

Comment: The name of my cup is called Plastic Cub and have another object called Water Bottle (so on my AR scene have 2 objects)

Comment: and sure I wont be using my method - I want to see if your method works or if you a working code with my method that will be great!

Comment: and why are you instantiating them on touchphase.began?

Comment: cause I will be using on ios devices thats why

Comment: man, and why you want to clone 2 objects on every screen touch from user?

Comment: the object I place are different, one is a cup and second is a water bottle. So, when I click on a particular object I want the sound out

Comment: oh cmon, Instantiate is not for making sounds

Comment: then how can I make it work? of what I intend to do

Comment: Instantiate is for clonning objects, your script will clone as many cups and bottles as much you touch your screen, and as i guess you dont need that

Comment: No I dont need that

Answer (score 1):

So, After realizing you problems I changed this answer.

At first your code must be attached only one gameobject, for example camera, like this[image: like this]

also I named my script StackOverflow, you can name it whatever you want.

And BoxCollider must be attached to your plastic bottle or cup, like this[image]
you can set it to trigger or nontrigger(depended on your necessity) and set its size to fit the real size of your objects in the scene.

and at last this is the Script which I named StackOverFlow, and SpeechToText in your case

```
public class StackOverFlow : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] AudioClip _audioClip;
[SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] float _volume = 1;
AudioSource _audioSource;
bool isPlaying;

void Start() {
    _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    _audioSource.clip = _audioClip;
    _audioSource.volume = _volume;
}

void Update() {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {

        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

            Ray touchRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            Physics.Raycast(touchRay, out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity);

            if (hit.collider != null) {
                if (hit.collider.name.Contains("Cup") || hit.collider.name.Contains("Bottle")) {
                    PlaySound();
                }
                else {
                    Debug.Log($"otherobject {hit.collider.name}");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

private void PlaySound() {
    if (!isPlaying) {
        _audioSource.Play();
        isPlaying = true;
        StartCoroutine(CheckIfPlaying());
    }
}

private IEnumerator CheckIfPlaying() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_audioClip.length);
    isPlaying = false;
}

}
```

ask me in comments if something is unclear

Comment: I have this setup on my scene: https://imgur.com/a/gpgekS0 and I tried your code above and it did not work. Did I setup properly on my scene?

Comment: Attach them BoxColliders

Comment: I attached BoxColliders on each of my objects and now I dont get my sound coming out when I tap on the object(s)

Comment: Attach this script to only one object, for example camera, and attach box colliders to plastic cup and water bottle, not their child objects

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gMfDJ8z in this should I apply a sound or I already have it on my object(s)?

Comment: You must apply sound on you SoundToPlay variable, and also first 2 lines are not necessary and you can remove them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212719/discussion-between-mike-and-chestera).

Comment: it does, but it plays both audio when I click on a object.

Answer (score 0):

So you seem to be misunderstanding the use of OnTriggerEnter, you would be better raycasting from the touch position and playing based on that

```
void Update()
{
    Camera mainCam = Camera.main;  
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
    {
        Vector3 touchPos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.forward);
        if(hit.gameObject == this.gameObject){
            // play sound
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it matter `Camera mainCam = ..` that it is AR Camera instead? also in your `if(hit.gameObject == this.gameObject)` am I going to say `_audioSource.PlayOneShot(SoundToPlay, Volume);` ?

Comment: `Camera mainCam = Camera.main` was a hack to show you the gist, you can serialize the field and set it up correctly for your camera, and yes so long as your audioSource is wired up correctly that should work. If you're having issues with other colliders blocking your object you can use the multi-hit function and cycle through them but that's only relevant if it's a problem

Comment: Also i assumed your game was 2D, you'll obviously need to use [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) if you're in 3D